# Better Junk filtering for outlook.com

Tags: spam-prevention, outlook.com

I am using Hotmail (which is now outlook.com) so I am using the web client.

Is there any way to get better junk filtering?  Like a plugin or a way to make a plugin where I can really manually analyse the mail and filter it myself?

The current junk filtering and sweep options are insufficient to filter the torrent of junk I'm getting.

Comment: You would have to use a desktop client, like Outlook, with an add-on to get this feature

Comment: @matt As you've no doubt surmised, questions specifically about Outlook.com are more appropriate for Web Apps.